# PayPal Payflow redirects to Express Checkout, instead of showing Hosted Checkout page with card fields

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm trying to use Hosted Checkout pages of Payflow. I got the PayPal team connect my Sandbox with the PayPal manager account.

When I open the https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com with form POST with having the SECURETOKEN and SECURETOKENID in fields (with or without any other fields from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/integration-guide/configure-hosted-checkout/) the Express Checkout is started with the PayPal login page.

When I set any field (like name, email) mandatory on PayPal Manager, then sending the form opens the Hosted Checkout page with an error message noting that name, email is mandatory and missing. If I provide them in the form, then again the Express Checkout is displayed.

What do I have to do to display the Hosted Checkout page with credit card fields?

Comment: Typically Express Checkout is one of the options *within* the Hosted Checkout page, and below that option there can be others -- including a Credit Card form which is the main reason to use Hosted Checkout pages.  Is that credit card form not showing up for you? Or what is your question?

Comment: My problem is that the Express Checkout is not an Option being showed on the Hosted Checkout page, but the only way to go. When the form is submitted, I'm redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=EC-xxxxxx.
I'm staying on https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/ (thus can use the Hosted Checkout page) when I force the error "Some required information is missing or incorrect."  with settings. On this page I have Pay with Paypal and pay with credit card options.

Comment: Is your account set up for other tender types, like credit card processing? Sounds like you're missing something then. You should post your complete request and response to obtain the secure token. But ultimately, this might be the sort of problem only Payflow support can troubleshoot for you.

Comment: I have secure token. If I don't post the secure token and secure token ID, " Error: Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist!" is returned. this is correct. When I'm requesting the token, I'm sending all the details of the transaction too (name address, postcode, amount, invoice)

Comment: Not sure if you responded to my whole comment. But we can't help with something we can't see (you did not post your CREATESECURETOKEN=Y request and response, and you did not post an example of your actual form post to pilot-payflowlink) , and ultimately this is something only Payflow support may be able to get to the bottom of for your account.

Comment: I've asked them as well, but last time your answer was faster and more helpful ;-) 
Thanks!

Comment: I'll look over what you're sending for any issues if you post a sample request/response log.  For what it's worth, Payflow Link is very dated, 10+ year-old technology.  Great for its time, but today instead of Hosted Checkout Pages, I would consider something modern such as Braintree Direct if you need it a full gateway, or just the black “Debit or Credit Card” form of Smart Payment Buttons. You can see a demo of the latter here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207303/discussion-between-tete-and-preston-phx).

Answer (score 0):

The CREATESECURETOKEN=Y request had TENDER=P wich is for PayPal Express Checkout

To show the Payflow Link / Hosted Pages credit card form, pass TENDER=C